# JavaFX switch to different scenes with one button

Tags: java, javafx

I was creating an application and wanted to change screens with one button depending on a number the user inputs. For example, if a user enters "1234", the program checks another class to see if that number is there. If it is, you go on to SceneOne. If the number the user enters is in reverse compared to the number in the other class, then you go to SceneTwo. However, when I try to set the location to a different scene, it just ignores it and automatically sends me to the first screen.

Storage.Java (contains a pre-defined number)

```
int pin = 1234;
public int getPin() {
    return number;
}
```

My other class: (function executes when button it is assigned to is pushed)

```
public void switchScenes(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/application/ScreenOne.fxml"));
    Parent changeScenes = loader.load();
    Scene firstScene = new Scene(changeScenes);
    Stage window = (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    Storage a = new Storage();
    int pin = a.getPin(); 

    if(Integer.parseInt((screen.getText())) == pin) {   
    //screen is a field where user can enter a number
        window.setScene(firstScene);
        window.show();
    }

    else if(Integer.parseInt(screen.getText()) == reverseNumber(pin)) {
        //if number entered is in reverse, change to ScreenTwo
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/application/ScreenTwo.fxml"));
    }
```

Comment: So, what is your question? Just add another scene...

Comment: I updated. I wanted it to go to a different screen if the number was different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer a format for changing the scene on a single stage:
On the sixth line is the desired .fxml object. You can simply make an if-then statement and load whatever .fxml object you want based on the input. This is a proven snippet of code I rely on when I want to change the scene in my projects.
{

```
@FXML
public void buttonclicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException //This method loads a new scene in a current window
{
    //note that on this line you can substitue "Screen2.fxml" for a string chosen prior to this line.
    Parent loader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen2.fxml"));//Creates a Parent called loader and assign it as ScReen2.FXML

    Scene scene = new Scene(loader); //This creates a new scene called scene and assigns it as the Sample.FXML document which was named "loader"

    Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow(); //this accesses the window.

    app_stage.setScene(scene); //This sets the scene as scene

    app_stage.show(); // this shows the scene
}
```

}